# Jenkins build fails with 'Cannot find executable from the chosen Ant installation'

Tags: jenkins

While executing a Jenkins job, I am getting this error message and the build fails.

> FATAL: Cannot find executable from the choosen Ant installation "ANT"
>   Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure

Please help me; what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means what it says :)

You configured your Jenkins job to use a particular Ant installation, called "ANT".

But in the global Jenkins config, where you created this "ANT" installation, it seems you maybe provided a path that does not exist, or is not available on the machine the build is running on.

The easiest way to use Ant with Jenkins is to use the default "Install automatically" option, and let Jenkins download Ant for you when required.